# Show that n noncollinear points on a plane determine at least n lines

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Let $P$ be a set of $n$ noncollinear points on a plane. Show that pairs of points from $P$ determine at least $n$ lines.

Edit: I don't have my notebook. I know I should use a certain linear algebra theorem that starts with two sets (in application to this problem one of them is a set of points and the other a set of lines determined by the points) and the conclusion is that cardinality of one of them (set of lines) is greater or equal to the cardinality of the other (set of points). Regretably I don't remember the theorem and I think it's not a very known one.

Comment: How have you tried to tackle this problem? What ideas do you have, and why aren't they working?

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this would be to use induction.  The base case is obvious: $3$ noncollinear points determine a triangle whose sides are segments of $3$ lines.

Now suppose that you have $n$ points arranged arbitrarily in the plane (so that they are noncollinear), and assume that we are guaranteed $n$ lines between them.

Now take this system, and add in an extra point that is not collinear with the $n$ existing points.  Are we guaranteed at least one extra line to yield a total of at least $n+1$ lines?